# error loading FXML into JavaFX

Tags: svg, javafx

I converted a SVG file into FXML by preprocessing it with Scour (thus removing a lot of Inkscape-specific cruft), then using E(fx)clipse to convert it to FXML. So far so good.

Unfortunately loading the file into SceneBuilder or my own JavaFX application produces:

```
Cannot create instance of javafx.scene.paint.LinearGradient with given set of properties: [endY, endX, startY, proportional, startX, id, stops]
```

I don't understand how this happen. The element is

```
                <LinearGradient

                startX="55.337996399999994"
                startY="12.907512"
                endX="90.41469080000002"
                endY="12.907512"
                id="linearGradient3056"
                proportional="false">
                <stops>
                <Stop
                    offset="0.0"
                    >
                    <color>
                        <Color>
                            <red>1.0</red>
                            <green>1.0</green>
                            <blue>0.0</blue>
                            <opacity>1.0</opacity>
                        </Color>
                    </color>
                </Stop>
                <Stop
                    offset="1.0"
                    >
                    <color>
                        <Color>
                            <red>1.0</red>
                            <green>1.0</green>
                            <blue>0.0</blue>
                            <opacity>0.0</opacity>
                        </Color>
                    </color>
                </Stop>
                </stops>
            </LinearGradient>
```

Answer (score -1):

There is no property `id` in the `LinearGradient`, try removing it.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: If he removes the id the file will be opened in the scene builder or his JavaFX application so that is how that happens